# Is RDP keyboard input encrypted?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

I was wondering if there is any encryption for keystrokes and/or clipboard put into RDP connection. If someone is monitoring your traffic, would they be able to see what is input? Is there a way to change the encryption settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is encrypted.

> RDP is based on, and an extension of, the ITU T.120 family of protocols. RDP is a multiple-channel capable protocol that allows for separate virtual channels for carrying device communication and presentation data from the server, as well as encrypted client mouse and keyboard data. [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/remote-desktop-protocol)

By default, the encryption is set at a default level setting of *Client Compatible (medium)*

To increase the encryption level used by RDP through Group Policy. To do so:

- Open Group Policy (run command is gpedit.msc)
- Open Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Security.
- Select the *Set client connection encryption level*
- Enable the setting and then choose the encryption level, located under the *Options* section